# Command output window disappears on blur

Tags: neovim

I'm using vim (actually, neovim) on macOS and whenever I run a command which outputs text (e.g. `:version`) and switch to another Desktop (so iTerm looses focus) and get back to it, the output window/pane is gone.

How can I stop it from automatically closing, even when the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` is shown? (which is actually a lie, as it continues without me pressing ENTER or typing a command)

Comment: probably a FocusLost/FocusGaines autocommand that closes the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known Neovim bug: [Focus events make messages disappear (as if Enter was pressed)](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/4840).

The workaround is either using Vim (which doesn't have this bug) or using a terminal emulator which doesn't send focus events (or disable sending focus events for your terminal emulator, if possible).

Comment: Any idea if I can disable focus events sending in iTerm?

Comment: This seems to be fixed now.